# Update whole object with Linq or must I bind each property?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I currently have this method which updates my university object and then saves the changes.

```
public static int Update(Models.University uni)
{
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var x = (from y in ctx.Universities
                 where y.Id == uni.Id
                 select y).FirstOrDefault();
        x.PrincipleName = uni.PrincipleName;
        return ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to save the whole object instead of setting each property?

For example something like(I tried this but the update fails):

```
public static int Update(Models.University uni)
{
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var x = (from y in ctx.Universities
                 where y.Id == uni.Id
                 select y).FirstOrDefault();
        x = uni;
        return ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `uni` is also an entity then you can just attach it to context

```
ctx.Universities.Attach(uni);
// set the state of the entity to modified so changes are saved
ctx.Entry(uni).State = EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have removed the first comment because when you Edit the answer I got my point